# xarray apply_ufunc to get the min and max for every variable

Tags: python-xarray

I currently have:

```
xds = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature')
xds['airx2'] = xds['air'] * 2

def _min_max(x):
    return np.min(x), np.max(x)

xr.apply_ufunc(_min_max, xds, input_core_dims=[['time', 'lat', 'lon']])
```

Which returns:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
   air      object (221.0, 317.4)
   airx2    object (442.0, 634.8)
```

How do I expand each data variable to have a min / max coordinate, or min_air, max_air, min_airx2, max_airx2 data variables so that I'm not working with object dtype and instead float?

I tried

```
xr.apply_ufunc(_min_max, xds, input_core_dims=[['time', 'lat', 'lon']], output_core_dims=[['min', 'max']])
```

but it errors:

```
ValueError: applied function returned data with unexpected number of dimensions: 0 vs 2, for dimensions ('min', 'max')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want expand along a new dimension, you need to (1) return a numpy array instead of a tuple and (2) specify the new dimension in `output_core_dims:

```
def _min_max(x):
    return np.array([np.min(x), np.max(x)])

>>> xr.apply_ufunc(_min_max, xds, input_core_dims=[['time', 'lat', 'lon']],
...                output_core_dims=[['min_max']])
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (min_max: 2)
Dimensions without coordinates: min_max
Data variables:
    air      (min_max) float32 221.0 317.4
    airx2    (min_max) float32 442.0 634.8
```

Alternatively, you can return a tuple of arrays from the applied function, in which case you'll get out a tuple of xarray objects from `apply_ufunc`:

```
def _min_max(x):
    return np.min(x), np.max(x)

>>> xr.apply_ufunc(_min_max, xds, input_core_dims=[['time', 'lat', 'lon']],
...                output_core_dims=[[], []])
(<xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:  ()
 Data variables:
     air      float32 221.0
     airx2    float32 442.0, <xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:  ()
 Data variables:
     air      float32 317.4
     airx2    float32 634.8)
```

Comment: How do I need to do if I want to apply the _min_max funtion along the time dimension to every lon/lat, i.e., return a dataarray that contain lon/lat dimensions.